# How to execute a command which ask for input in Rust

Tags: rust, command, command-line-interface, rust-2018

I am building a CLI using Rust-2018. It's a kind of wrapper around an old command.
I need to call that command in my Rust program but the thing is that the command asks for input (password) to perform the task.

Just like keytool when to need to generate a keypair and it prompts you to enter a password.

I want the called program to perform all his flow and only know if the program ends successfully or not.

This is what I have tried so far but it's not working as expected.

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

Command::new("...)
.args(&[...]
.stdout(Stdio::piped())
.spawn()
.expected("...)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just use piped stdin like you have already done for stdout. Then use the `Child` object returned by `spawn()` to obtain the child's stdin/out/err